# joblib.Parallel() slower than single for skimage

Tags: python, parallel-processing, cpu, joblib, parallelism-amdahl

I have to apply a 2D filter for every slice of a stack of images and I would like to parallelize the analysis. However, the code below runs slower than a normal for loop. Also, increasing `n_jobs` also increase the processing time, which is faster for **`n_jobs = 1`** and slower for **`n_jobs = 6`**.

```
import numpy as np 
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
from skimage.restoration import denoise_tv_chambolle

arr = np.random.rand(50,50,50)

def f(arr):
    arr_h = denoise_tv_chambolle(arr, weight=0.1, multichannel=True)
    return arr_h

Parallel(n_jobs=6, backend="threading")(delayed(f)(i) for i in arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *( Why ) ... **runs slower** than a normal for loop ( ? )*

```
>>> import numpy as np; _ = np.random.rand( 50, 50, 50)
>>> from zmq import Stopwatch; aClk = Stopwatch()
>>> 
>>> aClk.start(); r = denoise_tv_chambolle( _, weight = 0.1, multichannel = True ); b = aClk.stop(); print( "The code took {0: > 9d}[us]".format( b ) )
The code took    679749[us]
The code took    683137[us]
The code took    678925[us]
The code took    688936[us]
```

Given the miniature data shape `(50,50,50)`-of-`float64`, the in-cache computing is The Key for performance. Using a `joblib.Parallel` with a '**`threading`**' backend is rather anti-pattern ( python uses **`GIL`**-lock so as to re-`[SERIAL]`-ise the computing ***one-step-after-another***, as it avoids any kind of common, concurrency-related, collision ). Such serial flow of computing is even worse here, because the "switching" ***one-step-after-another*** is coming at an additional cost ( not improving the original purely-`[SERIAL]` code execution - so you pay more to receive the same (yet, after a longer time) )

> **Q** : *increasing **`n_jobs`** also increase the processing time*

Sure, it increases the amount of wasted time for the GIL-lock re-`[SERIAL]`-isation overheads as there are more **`one-step-after-another`** GIL-directed collision-avoidance "***switching***"-transitions.

---

### Last but not least

Even if going into a fully fledged parallelism, using the process-based parallelism ( avoids the costs of GIL-locking ), it comes ( again at a cost - process-instantiation cost ( a full 1:1 memory-copy of the python-interpreter process **`n_jobs`**-times in Win O/S, similarly in linux O/S - as documented in **`joblib`** module, incl. recommendations to avoid some other forms of spawning parallel processes ), parameter data-transfer-cost, result-transfer-cost ).

If one adds all these add-on costs for **`n_jobs = 6`**, and if these costs were accrued in the name of just a miniature computing-task ( as small as a **`~ 680 [ms]`** in duration ), one will soon result to **pay way more** to setup the parallel-processing **than will ever receive back** ( as other effect - as a worse-than original cache-re-uses - will not "increase" the speed of computing ).

**The [real-world costs](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3)** ( and a due accounting for each class-of-(all-such)-costs ) **of computing payloads is the reason** *( Why ) ... **runs slower***

Comment: So, is there no way to make the process faster? I was trying np.memmap right now but it is still slow.

Comment: **`np.memmap()`-s are `~ 10 [ms]` per random-access**, in-cache data with a smart-re-use can be got in **`~ 0.5 [ns]`** ... so you try to get things many orders of magnitude **even worse with `np.memmap()`-s**